# Performance implications of using GADTs

Tags: performance, haskell, gadt

When [answering a question with a suggestion to use GADTs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418749/how-do-i-accept-parameters-restricted-only-by-type-class/5421652#5421652), some questions with regards to performance came up in the comments. The question involved a typeclass `PlotValue`:

```
class PlotValue a where
    value :: a -> Double
```

and my answer suggested using a GADT `Input`:

```
data Input where
    Input :: (PlotValue a, PlotValue b) => Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Input
```

but the details are, I suppose, immaterial.

I'm wondering about two aspects of performance:

**Time**:
Are there any runtime costs incurred by a pattern match like

```
case x of
    Input (Just a) (Just b) -> value a * value b
    _ -> 0.0
```

over and above the normal costs matching two `Maybe` values?

**Space**:
How much storage overhead does a value of type `Input` carry? My guess is that it carries the two `PlotValue` dictionaries around for each and every value of type `Input` (a 'pointer' each?), meaning that a `[Input]` will be much more inefficient in terms of memory use than using `(Just Double, Just Double)` or, better yet, `(# #Double, #Double #)` - if you store the results of `value` in a normal or unpacked tuple.

So, while I love the expressiveness GADTs give me, I've never thought about the performance aspects much. Can anyone tell me more about this (and any other hidden costs I might not be aware of)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you've nailed down the overheads.  For each existentially qualified variable you need the corresponding (pointer to) dictionaries.  This takes space, and worse, the method calls are going to be slow.  The (*) in your example will be an indirect function call, whereas with Double it would have been a primitive op.

Comment: However, a similar statement is true about OOP and objects of non-final classes (each such object passed into a method needs a pointer to a virtual method table or equivalent), and C++ or Java are high performance enough for plenty of applications. Of course in both of those languages you would use non-OO things like arrays for some things for performance. Obvious comment, but I wanted to put it in perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, confirming my suspicions! The `(*)` in the case expression seems to me like it is always used at type `Double -> Double -> Double`, since the result of `value` is a `Double`, though - but `value` will evaluated all the time and may be expensive (like parsing a `String`) so here plain `Double`s will do much better.